# Use existing PDO link in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pdo, orm, eloquent

I have a store built with Opencart. Now I decided to use Laravel's Eloquent ORM to speed up further modifications. But the problem is that Opencart already has database connection (using mysql PDO driver) and I don't want to create new connection with Laravel as I want to keep performance as high as possible, and multiple db connections could be expensive.

So can I use already created PDO instance in Laravel Eloquent ORM?